# How to call/ re-render a button in openui5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sapui5

I am using the below openui5 toggle button which is blue when pressed is true and grey when it is false. But the value of the button changes at some point of time. Is it possible to explicitly call the button to re render it.

```
 var   oToggleButton1 = new sap.ui.commons.ToggleButton({
                                    text : "Auto-Update",
                                    tooltip : "Update toggle.",
                                    pressed : true,
                                    press : function() {

                                        if(oToggleButton1.getPressed() == true){
                                            buttonStatus = "ON";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            buttonStatus = "OFF";
                                        }                                                           
                                        var oDialog1 = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog();
                                        oDialog1.setTitle("Alert!");    
                                        //alert('Auto update is turned '+buttonStatus);
                                        oDialog1.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "Auto update is turned "+buttonStatus}));
                                        //oDialog1.addButton(new sap.ui.commons.Button({text: "OK", press:function(){oDialog1.close();}}));
                                        oDialog1.open();
                                        oDialog1.close();
                                        refreshButtonDisplay=oToggleButton1.getPressed();
                                    },
                                    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L12 M12 S12"}),
                                  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to bind the ToggleButton's pressed property to a property in a model and let UI5's binding magic take care of all that. If UI5 sees that the property in the model changes, it will check the bindings of that property to see if there are any UI controls need an update as a result of that. If you have bound your ToggleButton to that property, UI5 will update/rerender the ToggleButton.

You could also change the "pressed" property of the ToggleButton directly from your controller, e.g.: oToggleButton1.setPressed(false) should also do the trick.

Comment: I have already tried that by binding pressed : flag where flag is a var which is by default true declared in my main tab view and calling the same I.e. oToggleButton1.set visible(true) in onAfterRendering in all the tabs controllers separately ..but the problem is while the logic works properly but while switching tabs the auto update button is not changing its color suppose if I have set it to off in another tab until unless I close and reopen it again

Comment: I have taken your code and put it into a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/poferi/edit?html,output. You can see that I can perfectly switch the button off and back on again using an external event (a timer in this case). If this is not what you are after of if there is any other code that may interfere, you may want to elaborate a bit more (in understandable English, with decent punctuation please).

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand what you are trying to achieve, maybe you could elaborate a little more, i.e. what value changes and when? Anyway... jpenninkhof is absolutely right with everything he said. However, since you are explicitely asking for how to rerender the button here is the answer:

```
oToggleButton1.rerender();
```

This will rerender the button (based on its properties of course...).

However, calling

```
oToggleButton1.setPressed(false);
```

or

```
oToggleButton1.setPressed(true);
```

will rerender the button automatically in case the value for the pressed property has changed.